# Uploading via SFTP over slow connection to temporary location then moving to real location

Tags: ssh, ftp, sftp, winscp

I have an issue where occasionally I need to work at Starbucks.

When I upload a PHP file the connection is slow so if a user tries to access the PHP file while I am uploading it they will of course be issues a fatal error.

This is very inconvenient to my busy websites. Is there a way that when a file is uploaded it can be uploaded to a temporary location, and then the server moves it to the real location once finished?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make WinSCP upload the file to temporary file and rename it once transfer completes automatically.

In Preferences go to the *Transfer > Endurance* tab and select *All Files* in the *Enable ... Transfer to temporary file name* box.

For details refer to:
https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_pref_resume

Comment: Wow, and there it is. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just upload the file to a temporary folder on the server and execute commands on the server to remove the old file and move the new file? It should move the file fast enough on the server to eliminate any hiccups the users would see unless their timing was just right.

Comment: That is not really a solution as I don't want any manual work involved.

Comment: You could have a script running in the background that checks a temporary folder, moves files to the main folder if they are present, and sleeps for a set amount of time until it checks again. You could make a cron job to do it too and eliminate the sleep.